# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n, f(x)=Ax$ where $A\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{R})$ Compute the derivative. $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n, f(x)=Ax$ where $A\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{R})$ Compute the derivative. $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

[image]

I don't know how to calculate the derivative of the matrix, but I assume that we calculate the derivative of each $a_{ij}$ in $M$. Well since each $a_{ij}$ is just a real number, would the derivative be simply the $0$ matrix?

Comment: Derivative of $f$ is not the same as derivative of the matrix $A$. $f$ is not a constant map so its derivative is not zero. You just need to use the definition to calculate the derivative of $f$.

Comment: How do I apply the definition here?

Comment: It depends on what definition you're using. The most direct way is to use this [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative).